# "Please put your password here: None" The None problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python email sender but its not working what is expected

it says "Please put your password here: None"

heres my code:

```
import sys
import time

def write(print):
    for i in print:
        time.sleep(.05)
        sys.stdout.write(i)
        sys.stdout.flush()


sender_email = (NOT SHOWING HERE ITS PERSONAL)
senderemaillogged = "sender email loaded\n"
write(senderemaillogged)
rec_email = (AGAIN PERSONAL)
recemaillogged = "receiver email loaded\n"
write(recemaillogged)
passwordquestion = "Please put your password here: "
password = input(str(write(passwordquestion)))
passwordlogged = "Data of password loaded\n"
write(passwordlogged)
message = input(str("What is the message? "))
messagelogged = "Everyting ready\n"
write(messagelogged)
```

thats not **ALL** of my code but this is the ***part i find the problem***

Comment: write return None so: input(str(write(passwordquestion))) will contain None

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `input(str(write(passwordquestion)))`, what *exactly* do you think that means, *step by step*? In particular, what do you think will be the result of the `str` function call, and why? As an aside, you should not use the name `print` for your function parameter, since that locally hides the built-in `print` function.

Comment: In your own words, why do you want to use a function like this anyway? What purpose does it serve to add delay and show the letters one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Its the call to `input()` which is printing `None`.

Do this instead:

```py
write(passwordquestion)
password = input()
```

btw at the next `input()` you meant to write this:

```py
message = input("What is the message? ")
```

Comment: no its not this

Comment: oh i understand, you are a genius

Comment: oh not worked :(